# Auto Generated HTML source code formatting

Tags: functions, wp-head

I've had this question for a long time and I was wondering if anyone had an answer for it. I know its not really important, but for someone like me who really likes *very* clean markup things like this are a realy pain...

So this is my header:

[image]

*As a sidenote, you can see its nice and minimal as I've removed the markup that Wordpress automatically places in the header.*

The red outlined section is everything that is generated in `functions.php` and as you can see it has no tab spaces besides the first line...

[image]

I know it's really trivial, but we are shooting to do the best job possible and I would really like to get this sorted. Does anyone know how to add the tab spaces?

In case it is important here is the finctions.php code:

```
function thx_javascript_detection() {
    echo "<script>(function(html){html.className = html.className.replace(/\bno-js\b/,'js')})(document.documentElement);</script>\n";
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'thx_javascript_detection', 0 );

/**
 * Enqueue scripts and styles.
 */
function thx_scripts() {  

    // Theme stylesheet.
    wp_enqueue_style( 'thx-style', get_stylesheet_uri() ); 

    // Load the Internet Explorer 8 specific stylesheet.
    wp_enqueue_style( 'thx-ie8', get_theme_file_uri( '/assets/css/ie8.css' ), array( 'thx-style' ), '1.0' );
    wp_style_add_data( 'thx-ie8', 'conditional', 'lt IE 9' );

    // Enqueue jQuery.
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery');

    // Font Awesome Script.
    wp_enqueue_script( 'font-awesome', 'https://use.fontawesome.com/41d213027b.js');
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'thx_scripts' );
```

*P.S. this site is in the early satges still so some things (like tagline, lol) will be changing.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I know it's really trivial

Yes. Yes it is.

> ...we are shooting to do the best job possible

Spending any time whatsoever on fixing tab indentation in your *output* HTML as opposed to focusing on the quality of your *source* code is **not** doing "the best job possible". You should be minifying your HTML on-the-fly anyway!

But for the sake of answering a question, you could use the `style_loader_tag` and `script_loader_tag` filters:

```
function wpse_248549_tag_indent( $tag ) {
     return "\t\t$tag";
}

add_filter( 'style_loader_tag',  'wpse_248549_tag_indent' );
add_filter( 'script_loader_tag', 'wpse_248549_tag_indent' );
```

However, this won't handle other output that might be attached to `wp_head` - you'll either have to use the same approach for other hooks (if available), *or* you could use a dirty bit of output buffering:

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'get_in_line::open', 1    );
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'get_in_line::stop', 1000 );
add_action( 'wp_head',   'get_in_line::open', 1    );
add_action( 'wp_head',   'get_in_line::stop', 1000 );

class get_in_line {
    /**
     * Start the output buffer.
     */
    static function open() {
        ob_start();
    }

    /**
     * Get the contents of the buffer and spring clean.
     */
    static function stop() {
        $lines = [];

        foreach ( preg_split( '/[\n\r]+/', ob_get_clean() ) as $line ) {
            if ( trim( $line ) !== '' ) {
                if ( strpos( $_line = ltrim( $line ), '<' ) !== 0 ) {
                    $_line = $line;
                }

                $lines[] = $_line;
            }
        }

        echo "\t\t" . implode( "\n\t\t", $lines ) . "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, I agree with you when it comes to minifying HTML... will have a think about it, but thanks for answering the question regardless. Your answer worked great for eveything except the title tag. Any ideas why?